# "reflink" filesystem API for macOS?

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

On linux, we have the call

```
int ioctl(int, FICLONERANGE, struct file_clone_range *);
```

to "reflink" files. APFS also supports COW and thus a similar system call should exist. However, the `clonefile` API can only clone whole files, not blocks within the file.

Is there something similar to the ioctl call?

Answer (score 1):

No, macOS does not currently have an API that allows you to clone only a range. You can use `clonefile()/clonefileat()/fclonefileat()` to clone a full file. After you have cloned the file, you can make changes to the clones ofcourse.

Comment: So basically, if files A and B share a block C, then I can deduplicate by creating a file with content C, clone C twice, and add the additional contents of A and B to each of the clones, and finally removing C?

Comment: Well, that would be a bit of a roundabout way of doing it, but I suppose so, yes. In simpler terms, if A and B share a block C - then make a copy of A, modify it to be like B and delete B.